# Validation Rule that Exempts a certain Account

Tags: validation

I'm trying to write a validation rule that will exempt a certain `Account` from the validation rule.  The conditions are `If the Quote_Issued_To is EricSSH Electronics and the Product_NCNR = 'Yes' don't make them go through this rule`.  I'm currently stuck

This sits on Quote Feedback

```
AND(

(AND 
(
Contains(Upper(Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Quote_IssuedTo__r.Name), "ERICSSH ELECTRONICS"),
IsPickVal(Quote_Part__r.Part__r.Product__r.NCNR__c, 'Yes'),
IsPickVal(Quote_Part__r.ProductId__r.NCNR__c, 'Yes'),
Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Expired__c = 'Yes',
NOT(Quote_Part__r.Quote_Channel__c ='Disti'),
NOT (ispickval(Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Region__c,'North America')),
NOT(Ispickval(Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Status, 'Approved'))
)),
NOT(OR($Profile.Name="System Administrator",$Profile.Name="Inside Sales Quote Approver")) ,
RecordType.Id = '012M00000008voE')
```

Comment: just to be clear -- what is the Sobject model behind this

Comment: It's on Quote Feedback

Comment: and you've tried decomposing the rule into smaller bits to see why the validation isn't working?  Sometimes, when I get stuck in a complex rule, I create formula fields for some of the expressions and expose on the UI; you also have access to the debug log which will inspect the sobject.field values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to use && and || but I believe this is what you are after:

```
IsPickVal(Quote_Part__r.ProductId__r.NCNR__c, 'Yes') && Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Expired__c = 'Yes' && RecordType.Id = '012M00000008voE' &&
NOT(Quote_Part__r.Quote_Channel__c ='Disti' && ispickval(Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Region__c,'North America') && Ispickval(Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Status, 'Approved') && 
($Profile.Name="System Administrator" || $Profile.Name="Inside Sales Quote Approver")&& Contains(Upper(Quote_Part__r.Quote__r.Quote_IssuedTo__r.Name), "ERICSSH ELECTRONICS"))
```

Comment: I see you added the RecordType can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It's in your code above I can remove it...

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Where is it failing, maybe I'm reading it wrong, can you write out what the business requirement is?

Comment: `If the Quote_Issued_To is EricSSH Electronics and the Product_NCNR = 'Yes' don't make them go through this rule`

Comment: I had that criteria outside of the NOT() not sure how I missed that one...

Comment: Sorry to ask you after I accepted, but how would I add the RecordType into this?  It's only required for a specific RecordType..  So I guess I needed RecordType id =/

Comment: NP I'll add that back in.